# Angularjs Submit form within form for file upload

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, file-upload

I have a page that has a form on it. One of the things I need to include on the page is the ability to upload a file. I am trying to do this by using another form with an  in it. When the user selects the file, I want to get the file name and then perform the actual upload. From what I read, I cannot submit a form within a form, because the submit button in the inner form will also submit the outer form. I have tried looking for options and found the following page.

[Can I trigger a form submit from a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003188/can-i-trigger-a-form-submit-from-a-controller)

I thought that if I used this type of directive, then submitted it with the commit, then it should work....my problem is that for some reason when I try to access the form in my controller, it is showing as undefined. I think I need the form so that I can get the file name of the selected file...there may be a different way to achieve this than what I have tried but I haven't found it yet...

The latest controller, directive, and HTML files are below.

```
Controller:
$scope.uploadIt = function($form) {
    console.log($form);
    if ($form.$valid) {
       $form.commit();
    }
};

HTML:
<form editable-form name="editableForm" onaftersave="update" >
   <tr>
       :  other fields here....
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        <form  ng-form-commit name='fileForm' action="scripts/upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
            <p class="help-block">Upload a file to link it with this project.</p>
            <input type="text" name="prgGuid" id="prgGuid" value="{{programId}}" style="display:none;">
            <input type="button" ng-click="uploadIt(fileForm)" name="submit" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-default">
        </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>

Directive:
app.directive("ngFormCommit", [function(){
  return {
    require:"form",
    link: function($scope, $el, $attr, $form) {
        $form.commit = function() {
            $el[0].submit();
        };
    }
};
```

}]);

One more this that I will need to do....when the file is actually uploaded, I will actually be changing the file name so it is unique. Once the file is uploaded, I will need to pass back the new file name to my controller so I can store/display it. So I will need the original name the user selected and the new name...my php file will pass it back. I was thinking at first that maybe I could use a $http.post to submit the form and get the information back, but I couldn't get the file name the user selected. I was thinking if I could use the http.post to process the php file, then I wouldn't run into the form inside form, submit issue.

Please can someone tell me the easiest way to accomplish uploading a file with the form inside form constraints I have? I have been trying various things from posts I have seen but on here but I haven't found anything similar....please help. Thanks.

Comment: why to use two form, instead you can use custom file upload directive.

Comment: well the first form has a lot of information the user is also filling out. the second form was only because it was a way I had done it once before but there was only one form in that case. I tried using the directive above, but it doesn't seem to be working. If you can point me in the direction of an example that I can use, I will try it too. I have tried quite a few that I've seen on here.