# Issues with Yes/No Radio Buttons (Need to block submission if "yes" is selected)

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I'm having some issues trying to find the best course of action to block a form submission from going through if the answer to a yes/no question or at least give an error message properly.

First attempt was simply adding required="true" to the "No" button:

```
<th valign="top" align="left">
    <label for="yesOrNo">
        <strong>Are you a bad guy?</strong>
        <br />
        <br />
    </label>
</th>
<td valign="top">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" id="yesOrNo" value="yes" />Yes</label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" id="yesOrNo" required="true" value="no" />No</label>
    <br />
    <br />
</td>
</tr>
```

Then after that didn't work fully with "yes" still being valid for submission I tried making a hidden field that's required through angular which worked for me in the past. Granted this worked for a text field and numbers, I took an estimate on what to use in the case of a yes-no radio button:

```
<th valign="top" align="left">
    <div ng-if="angularYesOrNo=true">You are uneligible for this promotion</div>
    <label for="yesOrNo"><strong>Are you a bad guy?</strong>
        <br />
        <br />
    </label>
</th>
<td valign="top">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" ng-model="angularYesOrNo" id="yesOrNo" value="yes" />Yes</label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" id="yesOrNo" value="no" />No</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="badGuyFlag" id="badGuyFlag" ng-required='angularYesOrNo=true' />
    <br />
    <br />
</td>
</tr>
```

Is there anything in either code that I would need to change to make this work? Or is there any functions I would need to add in a separate script tag? This has been racking my brain all afternoon.

Comment: I don't do angular, but something like this would work in vanilla js:  `form1.addEventListener("submit", function () { var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']"); for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) { if (radios[i].value === "yes" && radios[i].checked) { return false; } } form1.submit(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ozYc9EMGbsRueD32NrlC?p=preview)**

It looks like you need to define your variable in your Angular Javascript file like this:

**Javascript**

```
$scope.angularYesOrNo = {bad:undefined};
```

Your ng-if statement needs two equal signs to evalute your `angularYesOrNo` variable.

**Html**

```
<div valign="top" align="left">
  <div ng-if="angularYesOrNo.bad=='Yes' ">You are uneligible for this promotion</div>
  <label for="yesOrNo"><strong>Are you a bad guy?</strong>
    <br />
    <br />
  </label>
</div>
<div valign="top">
  <label>
      <input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" ng-model="angularYesOrNo.bad" id="yesOrNo"  value="Yes" />
      Yes
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" ng-model="angularYesOrNo.bad" id="yesOrNo"  value="No" />
    No
  </label>

  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-submit` on the form to set a submit handler which validates the form data before it is submitted.

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="processSubmit()">
    <label><input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" ng-model="angularYesOrNo" id="yesOrNo"  value="yes" /> Yes</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" ng-model="angularYesOrNo" id="yesOrNo"  value="no" /> No</label><br />
```

In your controller define the function.

```
$scope.angularYesOrNo = '';
$scope.processSubmit = function() {
    if ($scope.angularYesOrNo == '' || $scope.angularYesOrNo == 'Yes') {
        // the form should not be submitted
    } else {
        // process the form (submit or ajax)
    }
};
```

And if you want to trigger the form submit from the controller see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25102791/5509627