# AngularJS - submit form programmatically after validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, postback

I have recently started working on AngularJS 1.6.

I am trying to submit a form programmatically. The reason is I want to validate a few fields (*required field validation*). I have spent a lot of efforts (probably 3-4 hours) trying to make this work but none of the existing answers on stack overflow or AngularJS docs seems to be working for me today (strange), hence I am posting this as last resort.

Below is my html

```
<form method="post" id="loginform" name="loginform" ng-submit="loginUser()" novalidate>
    <div>
        {{message}}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>User Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtUserName" ng-model="user.UserName" name="user.UserName" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtPassword" ng-model="user.Password" name="user.Password" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="btnLogin" title="Save" name="btnLogin" value="Login" />
    </div>
</form>
```

My angular code

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

demoApp.controller("homeController", ["$scope", "$timeout", function ($scope, $timeout) {   

    $scope.loginUser = function () {

        var form = document.getElementById("loginform");
        //var form = $scope.loginform; - tried this here...
        //var form = $scope["#loginform"]; tried this
        //var form = angular.element(event.target); - tried this...
        // tried a lot of other combinations as well...

        form.attr("method", "post");
        form.attr("action", "Home/Index");
        form.append("UserName", $scope.user.UserName);
        form.append("Password", $scope.user.Password);
        form.append("RememberMe", false);
        form.submit();
    };
}]);
```

I keep on getting error 'attr' is not a function.

All I need is submit a form using post method, with values. Just before that I am trying to intercept the submit call and check for validations.

I am open to try any other approach as well. Such as changing the input type from `submit` to `button`. Putting the input outside the form. I would be more than happy if validations and submit both can happen any which way. I just want it to post back the values after validating on the client side and then the server will take care of the redirect.

**Note:** I want the form to do a full postback so that I can get it to redirect to another form. (I know I could use Ajax, but some other day, may be!)

Comment: what validation you required

Comment: @bharatsavani savani Simple required field valdiations, for now

Comment: ok first remove both form.attr in you loginuser function add action in form tag

Comment: did just that, it postbacks, but doesn't carry the model values.

Comment: Should I be appending the form fields mannually?

Comment: i am post an answer

Comment: Okay, I will wait then. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137917/discussion-between-bharat-savani-and-devraj-gadhavi).

Comment: @Devraj Gadhavi do it the angular way instead of using the attr .. you dont need to use it ,

Comment: Instead of trying a "lot of other combinations", make an effort to understand how these APIs work. Both `.attr` and `.append` are not methods of HTMLFormElement. For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement).

Comment: A useful place to start understanding forms in AngularJS is: [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: Thank you for the links @georgeawg! I had seen some of the answers on SO using the `.attr` and `.append` with `form` element, hence, was trying in that direction. Sometimes you are so desperate that you don't look around. Probably that was the case with me yesterday. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the thing I was looking for. In the end I had to create a directive for validating and then submitting. So I am posting it here as a whole answer.

My HTML

```
<div ng-controller="homeController" ng-init="construct()">    
    <form method="post" action="Index" role="form" id="loginform" name="loginform" ng-form-commit novalidate class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="UserName">User ID</label>
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-not-empty"
                   id="UserName" name="UserName" ng-model="user.UserName" type="text" value=""
                   ng-change="userNameValidation = user.UserName.length == 0">
            <span class="field-validation-error text-danger" ng-show="userNameValidation">The User ID field is required.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Password">Password</label>
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-not-empty"
                   id="Password" name="Password" ng-model="user.Password" type="password" value=""
                   ng-change="passwordValidation = user.Password.length == 0">
            <span class="field-validation-error text-danger" ng-show="passwordValidation">The Password field is required.</span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnLogin" title="Login" name="btnLogin" value="Login" ng-click="validateUser(loginform)" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Look for *ng-form-commit* on the form element. It is the directive that I created.

My Angular code

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

demoApp.factory("commonService", function () {
    return {
        isNullOrEmptyOrUndefined: function (value) {
            return !value;
        }
    };
});

//This is the directive that helps posting the form back...
demoApp.directive("ngFormCommit", [function () {
    return {
        require: "form",
        link: function ($scope, $el, $attr, $form) {
            $form.commit = function () {
                $el[0].submit();
            };
        }
    };
}]);

demoApp.controller("homeController", ["$scope", "commonService", function ($scope, commonService) {

    $scope.construct = function construct() {
        $scope.user = { UserName: "", Password: "" };
    };

    $scope.userNameValidation = false;
    $scope.passwordValidation = false;
    $scope.isFormValid = false;

    $scope.validateUser = function ($form) {
        $scope.isFormValid = true;

        $scope.userNameValidation = commonService.isNullOrEmptyOrUndefined($scope.user.UserName);
        $scope.passwordValidation = commonService.isNullOrEmptyOrUndefined($scope.user.Password);

        $scope.isFormValid = !($scope.userNameValidation || $scope.passwordValidation);

        if ($scope.isFormValid === true) {
            $scope.loginUser($form);
        }
    };

    $scope.loginUser = function ($form) {
        $form.commit();
    };
}]);
```

I found the directive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003188/can-i-trigger-a-form-submit-from-a-controller...)

Answer (score 2):

1st of all avoid doing    `var form = document.getElementById("loginform");`.  Instead of using  `form.submit` you can use the following code. Do it the angular way cheers :D

```
$scope.loginUser = function () {
  if($scope.loginform.$valid){
      user.rememberme=false;

       $http({
         url: 'Home/Index',
         method: "POST",
         data: user 
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        // success
    }, 
     function(response) { // optional
        // failed
    });

  }
};
```

Comment: I was confined to do it the way I did (finally... phew), as doing the angular way would have required me to change the back end C# code, which was to be avoided. I know it's not the angular way, but that's for another time I guess. The project I am working on is not a SPA. I would have loved it to be a SPA and would have lived happily ever after. :D Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

this is a code to validation if validation not complate button is not enable

```
<form method="post" id="loginform" name="loginform" ng-submit="loginUser()" novalidate>
<div>
    {{message}}
</div>
<div>
    <label>User Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtUserName" required ng-model="user.UserName" name="UserName" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtPassword" ng-model="Password" name="user.Password"required />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit"  ng-disabled="myForm.UserName.$invalid || myForm.Password.$invalid" id="btnLogin" title="Save" name="btnLogin" value="Login" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have checked this, disabling the button approach. I would accept it as a last option. Because my application users are _used_ to click on the buttons and see validations getting fired. I do not want to change that behaviour as long as possible.

Comment: you have make a manual javascript function to validate your validation and show to user

Comment: Okay, if that's the only way then I'll probably work in that direction.

Comment: make a function of validate and check all inputs value in javascript

Comment: please up vote for me if you satisfied with my answer @DevrajGadhavi

Comment: Sure, I will, if I get it working with your suggested answer. I want to give sometime to others who might have a different answer that better suits my needs. If not I will definitely comeback and up vote. Be rest assured.

Comment: Thank you @bharat savani. I found what I needed somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You should use $scope when trying to access the form, something like `$scope.loginform`. But......
Take a look at ng-messages. Heres an example using ng-messages with your form:

```
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" ng-submit="loginUser()">
    <div>
        {{message}}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>User Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtUserName" ng-model="user.UserName" name="user.UserName" required/>
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="loginform.txtUserName.$error" ng-show="loginform.txtUserName.$touched">
            <p ng-message="required">Username is required.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtPassword" ng-model="user.Password" name="user.Password" required/>
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="loginform.txtPassword.$error" ng-show="loginform.txtPassword.$touched">
            <p ng-message="required">Password is required.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="btnLogin" title="Save" name="btnLogin" value="Login" ng-click="loginUser()" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Add ngMessages:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngMessages']);

demoApp.controller("homeController", ["$scope", "$timeout", function ($scope, $timeout) {   

    $scope.loginUser = function () {
      if($scope.loginform.$valid){
        //Code to run before submitting (but not validation checks)
      } else{
         return false;
     }
    };
}]);
```

Don't forget to include ngMessages in your app declaration and include the ngMessages.js script file. Note how you can simply use HTML5 validators.

Comment: Disabling the button approach would be a last option. Because my application users are _used_ to click on the buttons and see validations getting fired. I do not want to change that behaviour for them as long as possible.

Comment: I'd definitely give it a try with ngMessages and see what happens.

Comment: See edits, change the submit button to a regular button with a ngClick, and if the form is valid, submit the form.

Comment: Tried it, its posting back, but not getting the form values on the back end. Neither the validations are getting fired. No errors in the console :(

Comment: I tried with your latest edits as well. No luck in my case... Thank you for your help @garethb, I found what I needed somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Example using Angular 1.5 components.

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  function DemoFormCtrl($timeout, $sce) {
    var ctrl = this;
    this.$onInit = function() {
      this.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(this.url);
      /*$timeout(function() {
        ctrl.form.$$element[0].submit();
      });*/
    };

    this.validate = function(ev) {
      console.log('Running validation.');
      if (!this.form) {
        return false;
      }
    };
  }

  angular.module('app', [])
    .component('demoForm', {
      template: `
      <p>To run this demo allow pop-ups from https://plnkr.co</p>
      <hr>
      <p>AngularJS - submit form programmatically after validation</p>
      <form name="$ctrl.form" method="get" target="blank" action="{{::$ctrl.url}}" novalidate
       ng-submit="$ctrl.validate($event)">
        <input type='hidden' name='q' ng-value='::$ctrl.value'>
        <input type='hidden' name='oq' ng-value='::$ctrl.value'>
        <input type="submit" value="submit...">
      </form>`,
      controller: DemoFormCtrl,
      bindings: {
        url: '<',
        value: '<'
      }
    });

})(window.angular);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/rrruj6vlWrxpN3od9YAj?p=preview